# Auditd logs show that php-fpm delete my files

Tags: php, security, ubuntu, logging, audit

I got Ubuntu server with Nginx and php-fpm. I dont know why but sometime my files in web folder is deleting by unknown person (as i think). List of deleted files every time is same. I check logs all is ok. So then i installed auditd for Ubuntu. When my files were deleted again i seen this:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1531263705.847:98853): arch=c000003e syscall=87 success=yes exit=0 a0=7f8c948a5798 a1=1 a2=7f8c948a579f a3=1 items=2 ppid=1800 pid=15527 auid=4294967295 uid=1001 gid=1001 euid=1001 suid=1001 fsuid=1001 egid=1001 sgid=1001 fsgid=1001 tty=(none) ses$
type=CWD msg=audit(1531263705.847:98853):  cwd="/path.com/public"
type=PATH msg=audit(1531263705.847:98853): item=0 name="./" inode=1052665 dev=fd:01 mode=040775 ouid=33 ogid=33 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT
type=PATH msg=audit(1531263705.847:98853): item=1 name="./favicon.ico" inode=1045946 dev=fd:01 mode=0100664 ouid=33 ogid=33 rdev=00:00 nametype=DELETE
```

1800 pid is php-fpm, so as i see php-fpm create daughter process which delete my files? Is it possible?